# How to make buttons actively clickable when running a data search Windows Form (C# net 4.8)?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.8

My code currently is inside the using brackets:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader;

                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
.....
```

And, when the search is happening , all the UI controls remain un-clickable. For example, i have an Abort button to end the search if its taking too long, but that button is not clickable as the background search is happening.

What I attempted:

```
        private void abort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.Close();

        }
```

But, again I can't click any UI controls while the SQL connection stays open in the Windows form GUI..

Any ideas or workaround?

Comment: Do you mean that the application is frozen because it's executing a long-running process?  Are you then asking how to perform operations in a separate thread?

Comment: The code you've posted really has nothing to do with your issue. The issue is that you're performing a long-running operation on the UI thread. If you wait for the operation to complete, then the button(s) will be _clickable_ again. Or you could write code that doesn't block the UI thread.

Comment: Look for where you're executing your query, and call the appropriate async method instead. (e.g. instead of `var results = command.ExecuteReader(...);` do `var results = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(...);`

Comment: Yes, the code is being run in the background for a long running process, and disables the UI buttons while its running the background process.

Answer (score 0):

There is an asynchronous implementation of the ADO.NET methods as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming

Or alternatively, you can check out the `BackgroundWorker` class since you are using Windows Forms, or the `Task` class.